# Phalcon paginate return model

Tags: pagination, phalcon

I have a relational table.
I want to paginate one table and return as Model.
Because I need to model that belongs other model.
But `$paginator->paginate()->getItems()` always return `Phalcon\Paginator\Adapter\NativeArray` type. I need to return `Model`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are talking about phalcon 4

it will always return an array of arrays there is no way around that.

you can cache your table results and then loop through them using an identifier from the array.